# What does "skip to generate" mean when using the web2py application wizard

Tags: web2py

I'm at Step 4 in the web2py application generation wizard and I see a button labeled "skip to generate" and I'm wondering what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step of the wizard is where you generate the actual application code for the application you configured in the wizard (with options regarding exactly what portions of the app code to generate). The "Skip to generate" button appears on each step of the wizard and simply skips ahead to the last step, where you can then generate the code. Any steps you skip will simply retain the defaults.